# HTML object tag reset after fallback, is it possible?

Tags: html

I am using an `<object>` tag to display document previews on my website.
Essentially, I pull out the document URL and type from my database, and give it to the `<object>` tag as follows:

```
<object data="url" type="type" width="100%" height="100%">
 <p>Fallback in case the browser couldn't display the document</p>
</object>
```

Every time the user selects a different document, I just replace the two parameters on the **same** `<object>` tag (it's placed in a modal window).

Everything works fine, swapping documents works flawlessly, as long as the browser can render the documents (so, for example, moving from `image/jpeg` to `application/pdf` and back is fine).
However, as soon as one document cannot be rendered by the browser for any reason (e.g. the user doesn't have a PDF plugin), then all the following documents don't work either.

Is there any way I can reset the `<object>` tag, to be able to start showing documents again, without refreshing the page?

Otherwise, do you have any other suggestions to implement a document viewer other than with an `<object>` tag?

Thank you very much!

Comment: have you used something like try and catch... you could use $(object_id).html() trying to reset it....

Comment: @GuilhermeSilva, what do you mean? Could you please provide an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved by cloning the `<object>` element and injecting it into the DOM multiple times.

With jQuery:

```
var el = $("object");
el.clone().appendTo(el.closest("div"));
el.remove();
```

Thanks to @GuilhermeSilva for the input.